# Why use the copy function in languages?

Tags: python, function, copy, operators, variable-assignment

Just a philosophical question, I'm a rookie python programmer and I really like it, my question is, in any data type that uses the copy function (i.e. Lists, tuples, sets, etc.), why to use it instead of using the Assignment operator (=) like :

```
List_new = List_Old
```

Instead of writing:

```
List_new = List_Old.copy()
```

Literally, Why???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: The 2nd one makes a (shallow) copy and the 1st one doesn't make a copy at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if use assignment operator ‘=‘ to assign the list to new list it doesn’t make a copy but now both of them point to the same list, any changes you make to the new list will be reflected in the original list also i.e if you add an element to the new list it will also be added to original list and same happens if you remove  list elements. But if you use copy() function to copy a list to a new list any changes you make in the new list won’t be reflected in the original list.